# How to checks raised exceptions in phpunit tests?

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing, laravel-exceptions

In laravel 9.26.1 app I make tests with phpunit ^9.5.10 and I want to make checks on raised
exceptions on login with invalid credentials
In app/Http/Requests/Auth/LoginRequest.php I see :

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();
    if ( ! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }
```

I try to catch ValidationException and I found branch :
[Testing Exceptions in PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718513/testing-exceptions-in-phpunit)

But adding code in my test :

```
public function testLoginWithFailure()
{
    ...
    $response->assertStatus(302);  // Redirection status
    $response->assertRedirect('/');
    $this->assertGuest();
    $this->expectException(ValidationException::class);
```

I got error in cosole running tests :

```
1) Tests\Feature\AuthTest::testLoginWithFailure
Failed asserting that exception of type "Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException" is thrown.
```

Here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-tests I do not see any expectException method described...

How can I make checks on raised exceptions  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not how method expectException can work,
but calling method

```
$response->assertSessionHasErrors('email');
```

makes the same functionality I need and it salved my issue.